# Weird way to factor $2x^4 - 15 x^2 -27.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

A normal person would factor  $2x^4 - 15 x^2 -27$ by treating $x^2$ as the variable.  I'm grading a test now and the student has come up with the extremely clever idea to add and subtract $6x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x$ which makes the factoring run like this:

$$2x^4+6x^3+3x^2+9x-6x^3-18x^2 - 9x -27$$

$$= x(2x^3+6x^2+3x + 9) - 3(2x^3+6x^2+3x + 9)$$

$$= (x-3)(2x^3+6x^2+3x + 9).$$

The second polynomial also factors further.   How on earth could an 8th-grade B+ student come up with this scheme," I wondered.  So I typed "factor $2x^4 - 15 x^2 -27$" into Google and the very first hit shows using exactly this method.  I'm 100% sure this young lady (virtual student supposedly supervised by her mother) googled every answer on her test, including this one.  But I was stunned that THIS was the Google answer.

So finally my question:  Is there some known technique for cooking up the thing she added and subtracted?   (And why would Google pass over the obvious method...?)

Comment: Well, the method simply observes that $x = 3$ is a root of the polynomial and then add-subtract terms to extract that root out. As to the student, I can't suggest how she should be treated...

Comment: @WhatsUp  Why wouldn't one just divide by $x-3$?  I'm sure the girl cheated.  That aside, it seems odd that the Google answer, which is otherwise so pedantic, gives its first step what I wrote above.

Comment: If/when I suspect a root like $x=3$, and don't have Mathematica handy, I do the add-subtract thing, although I tend to do it term-by-term: $$\begin{align}&2x^4\color{red}{-6 x^3 + 6x^3}-15x^2-27\\ \to\quad &(2x^4-6x^3)+6x^3\color{red}{-18 x^2+18x^2}-15x^2-27 \\ \to\quad
&(2x^4-6x^3)+(6x^3-18x^2)+3x^2\color{red}{-9 x+9x}-27 \\ \to\quad
&(2x^4-6x^3)+(6x^3-18x^2)+(3x^2-9x)+(9x-27) 
\end{align}$$
etc.

Comment: @B. Goddard: because it’s more elegant (or more standoffish) this way? If you’re writing a math paper, you’d rather use the elegant trick that makes everything work like a charm than do computations to brute force it out?

Comment: From rational root theorem you know the root is $x=3$

Comment: @Fakemistake  No, you only know that $3$ _might_ be a root from the Rational Root Theorem.  Google is giving a really hard step without explanation, and then holds the readers hand through the rest of the exercise.

Comment: Can't answer your question about why Google would do it this way, but I wonder does Google do it that way for every quadratic in $x^2$ one could type in, or did you just luck upon the one and only example where Google does this?

Comment: @Mindlack  Google here purports to be show you how to do the problem.  It's not trying to be elegant or to show off. (And it shouldn't.)  How it came up with $6x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x$ is a complete mystery in their explanation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I just typed in $3x^4 - 10x^2 - 8$ and it gave the same sort of answer.

Comment: If it was me, I'd like to do like this; 

$2x^4-15x^2-27=2x^4-16x^2+32+x^2-59=2(x^2-4)^2+(x^2-4)-55=\left( (x^2-4)-5 \right) \left( 2(x^2-4)+11 \right)=(x^2-9)(2x^2+3)=(x+3)(x-3)(2x^2+3)$.